# R date format - Software

Tags: r, date, graph

Good morning everyone,

I want to represent a graph with dates on the x-axis and prices on the y-axis. When I import the CSV document, I have no problem. Each type of information is in its column, and the dates are in a suitable format. But when I try to graph this data. I get non-conforming lines, and the date format is not the same (now: 0002, 0004, 0006, 0008, 0010, etc...). What can I do?
I thank you in advance.

Here is my code and the pictures:

```
#Put the data in a matrix p
p <-read.csv("JSE_Price_index_and_Total_Returns1.csv", header = TRUE , sep = ",")

names(p)
names(p)<-c("Date","Price Index","Total Return Index")

#Adjust maybe date format - i don't knowv

????

#Representer Price Index - plot:
plot(as.Date(p$Date),p$Price Index, type = "l", col="black", lwd = 1)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: please cf https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
p$Date <- as.Date(p$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")
 plot(`Price Index` ~ Date, p, xaxt = "n", type="l")
 axis(1, p$Date, format(p$Date, "%b %d"), cex.axis = .7)
```

[image]